# "Saved photo" alert popping up before the user allows permissions to photo library?

Tags: ios, swift, photo

When the user clicks on the button, it immediately triggers the "Photo has been saved" alert before asking the user for permission. If the user clicks no then the photo won't save, but the alert will still display. Is there an if else statement I could use to make it where no alert pop ups until the user has allowed access to the photo library?

```
@IBAction func savePhotoClicked(_ sender: Any) {


    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "This wallpaper has been saved.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are showing your alert controller way too soon. The call to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` is asynchronous. See all those `nil` values you are passing to the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th parameters? Replace those with proper values so you can call your alert when the call to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` actually completes and you can correctly determine if the image was actually saved or not.

```
@IBAction func savePhotoClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // show error
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "This wallpaper has been saved.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better, don't call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum. There is a proper modern PHPhotoLibrary way to write an image into the photos library, and this isn't it.

Comment: @matt That may be true but this answer explains why the OP is having their issue with their current code.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say it didn't.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi I used the code you provided, but the app crashed when I clicked the button.

Comment: What was the error message? And what class is this code in? What does it inherit from?

Comment: I put some breakpoints and it doesn't call anything in the button now. It is in a UIviewcontroller. @rmaddy

Comment: If `savePhotoClicked` is not being called at all then that has nothing to do with this answer.

Comment: Yep I had a bad connection on accident. Thanks! Answer solved. @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the value of `+authorizationStatus` (class `PHPhotoLibrary`) before doing anything. And you can also request to access Photo Library  using method `+requestAuthorization` if the status is `PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined`

More information: [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620745-authorizationstatus), [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization)

Answer (score 0):

Generally:

- Either you don't need to be notified when the writing of the image is finished (in many cases that's not useful), so you use `nil` for both parameters
- Or you really want to be notified when the image file has been written to the photo album (or ended up with a writing error), and in such case, you generally implement the callback (= the method to call on completion) in the same class that you called the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function from, so the `completionTarget` will generally be `self`

As the documentation states, the `completionSelector` is a selector representing a method with the signature described in the documentation, so it has to have a signature like:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

It does not have to have this exact name, but it has to use the same signature, namely take 3 parameters (the first being an `UIImage`, the second an `NSError` and the third being of `void*` type) and return nothing (`void`).

---

#### Example

You may for example declare and implement a method that you could call anything like this :

```
- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
    if (error) {
        // Do anything needed to handle the error or display it to the user
    } else {
        // .... do anything you want here to handle
        // .... when the image has been saved in the photo album
    }
}
```

And when you call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` you will use it like this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage,
   self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
   @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
   NULL); // you generally won't need a contextInfo here
```

**Note** the multiple ':' in the `@selector(...)` syntax. The colons are part of the method name so **don't forget to add these ':' in the @selector** (event the trainling one) when you write this line!

Comment: The question is in Swift, not Objective-C. It's best to post answers in the correct language.